# Extract Value from nested options

Tags: scala

What is the most concise way to get 10 out of `Some(Some(Some(Some(10))))`?

without resorting to some external library like Scalaz.

Comment: If you have an `Option[Option[Option[Option[T]]]]` I think you should reconsider the API structure.

Comment: Most concise? "Don't" (as @YuvalItzchakov says :))

Comment: If you do slick program and do couple of left outer joins, you will end up with option inside option inside option. the question above is an exaggeration... just to highlight the problem.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Is there a way to have a bound on a type which ensures that it implements `flatMap` ? Other than providing an implicit of a wrapping `TypeClass` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh not sure why you're asking me, but structural typing would do it. See the first example here: https://dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I have had this question for a long time and I stumbled on it once again while figuring out a generic way of solving the current question so that a single function can flatten lists and options. But I am totally stuck because of differences in `flatMap` of `Option` and `scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic`. The reflection duck-typing pattern does not seem to help here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import scala.language.higherKinds     

case class Flattener[W[_], WW, T](fn : WW => W[T])

implicit def optionRecFlattenFn[WW, T](
  implicit f : Flattener[Option, WW, T] = Flattener((ww: WW) => Option(ww))
) = Flattener((ww : Option[WW]) => ww.flatMap(f.fn))

def optionRecursiveFlatten[WW, T](www : Option[WW])(
  implicit f : Flattener[Option, Option[WW], T]
) = f.fn(www)

val nestedOption = Option(Option(Option(Option(10))))
// Some(Some(Some(Some(10))))

val flatOption = optionRecursiveFlatten(nestedOption)
// Some(10)

val evenMoreNestedOption = Option(Option(Option(Option(Option(Option(10))))))
// Some(Some(Some(Some(Some(Some(10))))))

val flatOption2 = optionRecursiveFlatten(evenMoreNestedOption)
// Some(10)
```

Comment: Good Answer. I still do not understand though on this `implicit f : Flattener[Option, WW, T] = Flattener((ww: WW) => Option(ww))` compiles

Comment: @Jatin did not get your question ?

Comment: What I mean is `Flattener((ww: WW) => Option(ww))` is `Flattener[Option, WW, Option[WW]]` and not `Flattener[Option,WW,T]`.

I understand on how it works (that implicit will only be used in the last case with single Option depth). But I am surprised that compiler does not raise a warning much before in compiling phase

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't know the nesting level in advance, this will work for any level:

```
def unwrapRec(o: Option[Any]) : Any = o match {
  case Some(inner @ Some(_)) => unwrapRec(inner)
  case Some(x) => x
  case _ => ???
}
```

However, please note that an `Any` is returned. You can change it to whatever type you like and adapt the pattern match accordingly but I think you will have to pass in an `Option[Any]`. So it's not typesafe at this point.

Comment: This is clearly suboptimal b/c the type system knows what is getting unwrapped. You did say that caveat, but 4 upvotes are four misapprehensions. (Edit: there should be no presumption of Any.) Someone just posted a typelevel solution...

Comment: Actually, I suspected there was a typesafe solution and I appreciate, someone posted it since I could not come up with it myself. It certainly gets my upvote. Anyway, since the question asked for the most concise way to extract the value from the nested options, I'd rather not call the upvotes misapprehensions (especially not in absence of the typesafe solution).

Comment: I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten` on nested `Option[Option[A]]` repeatedly:

```
scala> val a = Some(Some(Some(Some(10))))
a: Some[Some[Some[Some[Int]]]] = Some(Some(Some(Some(10))))

scala> a.flatten.flatten.flatten.get
res0: Int = 10
```

I do not think there is any generic and type-safe way to extract `A` from `T[A] := Option[T[A]] | A`.

---

Edit: This method can dynamically get the contents, returns either the innermost value, or `None`:

```
def unwrap(x: Any): Any = x match {
  case Some(v) => unwrap(v)
  case v => v
}

scala> unwrap(Some(Some(Some(Some(10)))))
res1: Any = 10

scala> unwrap(Some(None))
res2: Any = None
```

It has unfortunately too broad type: `Any => Any`.